# How to connect to the console router with limited length of roll-over cable?

Tags: cisco, cable

Here is the full question: I have a roll-over cable with length only 5 m and I want to connect it to the console of the cisco router that is 20 m far. How can I solve this?

Comment: Get a 15m straight-through cable and a "bulkhead" connector. At 20m, there may be issues with serial comms. RS-232 can work to that distance, but very few things actually obey the age old standard (+/- 25V.) The higher the speed, the less stable it will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twenty meters is too far for the serial link to work. I have been able to get up to about 10 meters with *some*, but not all, Cisco devices.

You need to set up a terminal server that plugs into the console port so you can connect to the terminal server on the network to get access to the console port of the device. There are all type of terminal server out there, but product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Years back there were *active* serial cables that could make the distance. Today, the possibly cheapest way is to use a USB extender with a USB-to-serial converter at the end - extenders using Cat-5 in between are good for 50+ m.